# Next.js and Mongoose and Passport.js: req.user is undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am using the relatively newer setup with Next.js API routes, this doesn't use express but instead the [API setup](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) to create your routes to an endpoint.

My problem is I'd like to have a route called `api/user` which will return the user i.e. `req.user`:

The following comes from [with-passport-and-next-connect](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-passport-and-next-connect/middleware/auth.js)

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect'
import auth from '../../middleware/auth'

const handler = nextConnect()

handler
  .use(auth)
  .get((req, res) => {

    if (req.session.user) {
      const { _id } = req.session.user
      res.json({ user: { _id } })
    } else {
      res.json({ user: null })
    }

  })

export default handler
```

That file references this [auth](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-passport-and-next-connect/middleware/auth.js) file:

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect'
import passport from '../lib/passport'
import session from '../lib/session'

const auth = nextConnect()
  .use(
    session({
      name: 'sess',
      secret: process.env.TOKEN_SECRET,
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 8, // 8 hours,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        path: '/',
        sameSite: 'lax',
      },
    })
  )
  .use((req, res, next) => {
    // Initialize mocked database
    // Remove this after you add your own database
    req.session.users = req.session.users || []
    next()
  })
  .use(passport.initialize())
  .use(passport.session())

export default auth
```

I have added this in my version:

```
  .use((req, res, next) => {
    connectDB()
    next()
  })
```

But that yields nothing.

In `api/login` I added this line

```
req.session.user = req.user;
```

after the authenticate function. But that doesn’t add the user to the session object.

```
   handler
  .use(auth)
  .post((req, res, next) => {
    emailValidator(req, res, next, 'email', 'password');
  },
    async (req, res, next) => {
      await connectDB();

      passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {

        req.session.user = req.user;
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.